The probability of drawing a diamond, then drawing an ace is equal to drawing the ace of diamonds.
The numbers work out the same: $\frac{1}{52}$
What is the reason behind this? The raw maths is simple and works out, but is there a way to show, or to reason, that they ought to have the same value?

Do you put the diamond card back in the deck?

this question is a duplicate.  I don't think there is any  more informative explanation than the (straight forward) computation.

I note that, in the duplicate, the posted solution claims to have a simple intuitive explanation, but I don't get it.  Or, at least, I don't see how writing it out is any clearer than the standard computation.

Without a clear answer to the question in the comment of Kolakoski54, the question is meaningless.

If the answer to Kolakoski54 is yes, or if it is not, it generates 2 different exercises. We can solve both exercises. And, luckyness or something else, result $\frac{1}{52}$ is correct in both cases.

@lulu I answered the earlier question since it was both earlier and more clearly stated than this one. I think there is a good intuition for why the events are independent, but it's also easy to show, so I did that too.

This is clearly not a duplicate question from the human perspective, even though the mathematical problem is the same. The linked question just asks to compute the probability, which the OP for this one clearly knows how to do ("[t]he raw maths is simple and works out"), and they're asking for a deeper or intuitive reason why they are the same. Let's not get so caught up in closing questions we have an immediate reaction to close questions with any slight bit of similarity to an existing one; slow down and appreciate the asker's motivation first!

There is indeed a nice reason: there's a probability-preserving map between the outcomes that maps the "top card is ace of diamonds" event to the "top two cards are diamond, then ace" event.
Consider any two distinct cards, then consider those two cards with their ranks swapped. You can check that after the swap, the cards are still distinct.* This means the rank swap operation is a bijection on the set of pairs of distinct cards (it's its own inverse).
The rank swap operation maps all "top card is an ace of diamonds" pairs to "top two cards are diamond, then ace" pairs, and vice versa. Therefore, the two events each capture the same number of outcomes, and thus have same probability of occurring as the top two cards in a uniform shuffle.
Generalizations:

As Karl notes in the comments, one can make a more general observation: "draw two random cards" and "draw two random cards, then swap their ranks" result in the same distribution over pairs of cards.

I implicitly assumed that the cards are drawn without replacement, because I restricted attention to pairs of distinct cards. But the same reasoning works when drawing with replacement, too: just don't worry about distinctness. In particular, the more general observation in the previous bullet point is immediate when drawing with replacement.


*The only way for them to not be distinct would be if they were the same after the swap. But that would mean the ranks are the same, so the swap wouldn't do anything, and we assumed the original cards were distinct.

OK, I finally read this carefully, and it's even nicer than the answer I posted on the earlier question. But I suppose this answer really does belong on this question because no matter how the question of "replacement" or "no replacement" is answered, you just showed why we get the same answer.

The implicit observation that completed this answer for me is: the top two cards of the deck are a random pair of cards, and "pick two random cards" and "pick two random cards and then swap the ranks" give the same (uniform) distribution over pairs.

That's a nice observation, @Karl, and a stronger one than what I observed in the answer. I'll add a comment at the end.

Consider a very similar question.
We have a deck of 52 standard cards. We exclude the 2 of Clubs.

What is the probability that the 1st card is the Ace of Diamond ? $\frac{1}{51}$
What is the probability to draw a diamond and then an Ace, without replacement ?$\frac{1}{50}$
What is the probability to draw a diamond and then an Ace, with replacement ? $\frac{52}{51^2}$

The answers to those 3 questions are different.
In the first problem (full deck 52 cards), the result of 1st card (diamond or not diamond) has no impact on the 2nd card. Even if we draw cards without replacement. Probability that 2nd card is an ace is $\frac{1}{13}$, no matter the 1st card is diamond or not.
It is certainly an important reason to explain why answers to Q1 and Q2 are the same with the full deck.

If you think about it, drawing a diamond first, then an ace means that the second card must specifically be the ace of diamonds. This is because:
1)if the first card is any diamond except the ace of diamonds, there is no way to draw the ace of diamonds as the second card.
2) If the first card is the ace of diamonds, the sequence works.
Thus, the two events are actually describing the same scenario: drawing the ace of diamonds over two draws in a specific order, which occurs with the same probability.

What? I could draw the queen of diamonds, then the ace of spades, and that would count as "drawing a diamond first, then drawing an ace". The second card does not need to be the ace of diamonds.

In that case, the math obviously doesn't add up to $\frac{1}{52}$.

You might want to rethink that claim, as it's false.
